# Adding subview to navigation bar with a search controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to add a custom subview button to my navigation bar and am having trouble placing it in the desired position. My goal is to have the button be centered with the title label, whether it is large or small. But for right now I am trying to anchor it to the bottom of the navigation bar. However, I can't access the the search bar to properly add the constraints.

[Current Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc2Of.png)

```
func setupNav() {
    guard let navController = navigationController else { return }
    let navBar = navController.navigationBar

    let settingsButton = UIButton()
    settingsButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "settings-button")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
    settingsButton.tintColor = .textColor()
    settingsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openSettings), for: .touchUpInside)

    navBar.addSubview(settingsButton)
    settingsButton.anchor(top: nil, left: nil, bottom: navBar.bottomAnchor, right: navBar.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 5, paddingRight: 10, width: 30, height: 30)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the search bar by using

```
navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this property of your button which makes you to add constraints programmatically:

`settingsButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

This is my code:

```
func setupNav() {
    guard let navController = navigationController else { return }
    let navBar = navController.navigationBar

    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openSettings), for: .touchUpInside)

    navBar.addSubview(button)
    navBar.addConstraints([
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: navBar, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: button, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 20),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: navBar, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    ])
}
```

Happy coding.